# ROS Answers SE migration: Error in hydro

Tags: catkin, ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just reinstall my distro hydro.
And I can't catkin_make
It said that the order is not found
What is the issue?
I'm in Ubuntu 12.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188796/error-in-hydro/) by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-08-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-08-04**:
please post the error. did you forgot source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash ?

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-04**:
No i did not forget. It said that the file /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you need to create your catkin workspaces (be sure that you are in regular user not the root user; if not type exit) :

```
$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ catkin_init_workspace
$ catkin_make
$ source devel/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) with karma: 751 on 2014-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-04**:
It says that catkin_init_workspace command not found

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-08-04**:
probably you create the catkin as root user !

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-04**:
So what should i do?

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-08-04**:
type "exit" if you are root user and then try to create your workspaces (it will be as regular user)

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-04**:
But is there a link with the fact that in my folder /opt/ros/hydro there is no file setup.bash?

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-08-04**:
so you didn't re install ROS correctly, try this echo "source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc  and    source ~/.bashrc then source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-04**:
It doesn't work!
when i launch   echo "source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc it says that the file opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash doen't exist

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-08-04**:
so you should re install it: http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu .....follow all the instruction in this link and then move to this 4.Create a ROS Workspace : http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment    ....and then tell me if it works or not

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-04**:
It work, I deleted all my distro, and reinstalled